# Custom "Not Found" with G-WAN Web Server on static content directory

Tags: http, custom-errors, g-wan, httphandler

**Custom "Not Found (including Text and Headers)" with G-WAN Web Server on static content directory**

Before I ask my question, note that I have figured out how G-WAN builds responses with scripted languages from the csp directory.

I just want to serve web static contents with G-WAN, and I can't find any resources about how to serve *custom HTTP errors*. An answer will be very much appreciated.

By the way, I really need a real example and not a simple "How To", because I'm not a C programmer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution after more research.

All I have to do is adding my main.c file into handlers directory of the hostname folder.

Thanks to those guys, who have been asked and answered to the followings:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847994/custom-404-response-for-gwan

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274326/can-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-the-default-headers/17296185#17296185